# Nativescript - Get the mail/name of the user who downloaded the app

Tags: angular, email, authentication, nativescript, identify

I'm on nativescript 6 with angular.

I wanted to know if that's possible already (i didn't found it) , to get the mail or name of the user who downloaded the app.

I explain myself, if the user is on android this will get the google play mail or name of the user he downloaded the app with. If he is on iphone this will get the apple store mail or name.

If i'm not understandable tell me.

I just need to identify the user without login and device name by default is just the model of the phone. Thank you !

Comment: I don't think iOS lets you do that at all. Android may let you do it by querying the account manager.

Comment: @Manoj just tried that, without success

Comment: If you have tried that I think you should add the related code and explain the issue further.